# How to distribute routes over several plugins

Tags: go, plugins, routes

I am currently working on a project which requires HTTP-Routes being distributed over several plugins. Currently fiber is the used framework, a switch to another framework is possible if need be.
The project is structured like this:

```
+ base
|
+-- main
|    | base-routes.go
|
+--plugins
|    |
|    + Plugin1
|    | plugin1-routes.go
|    | further files omitted
|    | 
|    + Plugin2
|    | plugin2-routes.go
|    |
```

Is there a chance of dynamically adding the routes depending on the installed plugins?
It would be perfect that after calling `go run base.go --plugins=plugin1` all the routes and only these routes are added to the main routes. On calling `go run base.go --plugins=plugin1,plugin2` all the routes should be established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Fiber and with other web frameworks as Echo, Gin, ... you can add routes conditionally just with `if` statements.

Initialization in Fiber looks like this (https://github.com/gofiber/fiber#%EF%B8%8F-quickstart):

```
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, World !")
    })
```

With conditional logic:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main() {

    cliflags := flag.String("plugins", "", "")
    flag.Parse()

    app := fiber.New()

    // verify not nil or something else according to your flag pattern
    if cliflags != nil {
        app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
            return c.SendString("Hello, World !")
        })
    }

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```